# AWS Kinesis S3 Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send data to Amazon Redshift through Kinesis via S3 using the `copy` command. The data format is ok in S3 in JSON, but when it reaches Redshift, lots of the column values are empty. I have tried everything and haven't been able to fix this for the past few days.

Data format in s3:

```
{"name":"abc", "clientID":"ahdjxjxjcnbddnn"}       
{"name":"def", "clientID":"uhrbdkdndbdbnn"}
```

Redshift table structure:

```
User(       
  name: varchar(20)     
  clientID: varchar(25)     
)
```

In Redshift I get only one of the two fields populated.

I have used JSON `auto` in the copy command.

Comment: You need to supply your actual code, not just a vague description of your code.

Comment: Your data in s3 has only two columns, so ideally after copy only two columns will have values, so what is the actual problem?

Comment: Can you check STL_LOAD_ERRORS to see if there are any errors while loading this data?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your COPY statement.

Comment: The error has been resolved. Thanks everyone for the help. The problem was redshift saves the column as clientid instead of clientID and the data from s3 has clientID. So, only the name field was populated and clientid field always empty. It's strange no exception occurs here.